# What kind of permission I need to assign?

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am doing some work in `Reporting Service 2005`. I need to call a COM object so I wrapped the call in custom assembly. The approach worked in preview. But when I deployed the report I ran into `#Error`. Microsoft has a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=842419) about this.

It says that I have to assert permission in my custom assembly.

But I do not know what permission I should assert?  My method looks like this:

```
public static String myEnocde(String strDataToEncode)
{
    //Get IDispatch Interface
    Type objEncoderType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ProgID");

    //Create Instance
    object objEncoder = Activator.CreateInstance(objEncoderType);

    // parameter
    object[] parameters = new Object[1];
    parameters[0] = strDataToEncode;

    try
    {
        //Invoke Encode
        Object resultObject = objEncoder.GetType().InvokeMember("Encode", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            Type.DefaultBinder, objEncoder, parameters);

        String strResult = (String)resultObject;

        return strResult;
    }
    catch( Exception theException ) 
    {
        <more code here>
    }
}
```

The code launches a COM object dynamically, and calls its method using late binding.

I added a `CodeGroup` in `rssrvpolicy.config`. The field still showed '#Error'.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a report the user making the call must have the role of "Browser". See:

http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/215.aspx